# graph rotation wrong direction

Tags: graphing-functions, rotations

I tried rotating the graph of the circle of radius 1 centered in (1,1) around the origin.
I used the formula from this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) page.

The green circle is the one I want to rotate, the black one is the result and the red line is just a visual indicator of the angle of rotation.

My problem is that in the page mentioned above it says:

*"The direction of vector rotation is counterclockwise if θ is positive (e.g. 90°), and clockwise if θ is negative (e.g. −90°)."*

Why is it then that in my image the rotation is clockwise but my angle is positive (45°)?

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Side question: What other function (must be a function) can I use instead of arctan to have the Function Image Domain be [-π, π]  or [0, 2π]? Right now I can't do a full rotation around the origin.

[image: Desmos was used to generate this image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the graph of function $f(x, y) = 0$

The image the point (x,y) on this graph under a rotation by $\theta$ is

$ (x',y') = (x \cos \theta - y \sin \theta, x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta ) $

To obtain the function $g (x', y') = 0$ representing all points, you have to solve for $(x, y)$ from $(x',y')$ given by the above formula, the result is

$ (x, y) = (x' \cos \theta + y' \sin \theta , - x' \sin \theta + y' \cos \theta) $

Now plug this expression into $f(x,y) = 0$ , this will give you $g(x',y') = 0$

So, in this particular example, $f(x,y) = (x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2 - 1 = 0$

So the rotated function when rotating by $\theta = 45^\circ$ is

$ ( \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (x' + y') - 1 )^2 + (\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(y' - x') - 1)^2 - 1 = 0 $

You can now replace the primed variables with unprimed variables to obtain the equation

$ ( \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (x + y) - 1 )^2 + (\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(y - x) - 1)^2 - 1 = 0 $

And this is the equation of the circle rotated $45^\circ$ counter-clockwise.

As for your side question, you can use the function $\text{atan2}(x,y)$, this will return an angle in $[-\pi, \pi]$. where $ x = r \cos \phi$ and $y = r \sin \phi , r \gt 0 $

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: At the second step, why do I have to solve for (x,y) in terms of (x',y')?

Comment: Because the original function is given in terms of x and y.